# .NET MAUI Sizing

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

How to set a size of, for example a rectangle, in .NET MAUI? If I set `Height="200"`, the rectangle is big for small phones and small for big phones. Is there a way to specify it in a percentage of the page size like in CSS?

Comment: Use Grid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Same problem, they use for example `Margin="20,21,22,23"` but this margin can be big on small Iphone SE but too small on Iphone 15 pro. I would like to use something as `Width="10%"` and it means 10% of display width.

Comment: @závislost That can still be achieved with a Grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Grid for this. If you want a relative margin, define extra rows and columns and leave them empty. For relative sizing and margins to work, you'll need to use the `*` ("star") for the sizes of the rows and columns:

```xml
<Grid
    ColumnDefinitions="*,8*,*"
    RowDefinitions="*,8*,*">

    <BoxView
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

</Grid>
```

This will put a 10% margin on all sides and the content always takes up 80% of the available space.

Then, you can use the `Fill` LayoutOption, for example, instead of giving your Rectangle (or any other control) a relative size when placing it in the Grid.

Comment: And how to do it verticaly in scrolling CollectionView. I understand how to do it horizontaly with use of *, but not sure how height can be changed this way. And same with Fonts (maybe if font can fill some cell, but still don't sure). And last thing, in documentation there is written, that you should avoid to use * because it is not good for performance. If there is no %, isn´t is better to get height and width of phone at the start of app and use the valuse to compute Width and Height? Thanks in advance

Comment: In the documentation it says to use `*` instead of `Auto`, because `Auto` has an impact on performance. From the documentation: *"Alternatively, set rows and columns to occupy a proportional amount of space with the GridUnitType.Star enumeration value."* Apart from that, you can also compute the Width and Height, but then you'll need to use lots of bindings, which is more work and impacts runtime performance. What do you mean by "how to do it vertically in scrolling CollectionView"?

Comment: I want to make Scrolling Area with "cards" of arrivals of airplanes. If I set `Margin="20"` for the card, it will look really nice on bigger phones, but when I run it on some small phone the margin is too big. So I thought I will use some "device dependent units" but now I now that it doesn´t exist and I am lost.                                               ...and sorry for "*" and "Auto" in previous comment, my mistake

Comment: You can [customize the UI appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/customize-ui-appearance) based on the device type (idiom), if that helps. There is also a markup extension to define specific breakpoints similar to how it's done in CSS: https://github.com/carolzbnbr/OnScreenSizeMarkup.Maui. ***One important remark**: Your question doesn't reflect any of these things. Please update your question with sufficient information, i.e. provide your code and some screenshots of what it looks like and mockups of what you need.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `AbsoluteLayout`

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Rectangle AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8"
               BackgroundColor="LightBlue" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The position and sizing of the children can be either absolute or proportional positioning. By setting `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"` we are requesting proportional positioning for `x, y, width, height`. Contrary to the documentation, under proportional positioning the `x, y` refers to the position of the child center relative to the parent, not the upper-left corner. So, for your application, you would want it to be `0.5, 0.5`. For the sizing, because you want 10% margin, that means the `width, height` should be set to 80%, i.e. `0.8, 0.8`. Note that when using `AbsoluteLayout` positioning and sizing must be via `LayoutFlags` and `LayoutBounds` properties as `HorizontalOptionals` and `VerticalOptions` have no effect.

Another caveat with `AbsoluteLayout` is there is no clipping, but, clamping of coordinates. So, if you were to set `x, y` to `0, 0` your object would be clamped to the upper-left corner. Alternatively, if you were to set `x, y` to `1, 1` your object will be clamped to the lower-right corner. By setting `x, y` to `0.5, 0.5` your object will be centered.

[EDIT]

You can mix `AbsoluteLayout` with conventional components if you wrap them in a `Grid`, e.g.

```xml
<Grid>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Rectangle AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8"
                   BackgroundColor="LightBlue" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" />
            <Label Text="Hello, World!" />
            <Label Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI" />
            <Button x:Name="CounterBtn" Text="Click me" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is great, but usually, you'll then end up putting everything inside that layout and it makes things quite complicated with the different things that need to be considered, such as the flags. It's a viable solution, though.

Comment: @Julian that was my thought initially, but, I recently found that it works well with `<Grid>` particularly when you can stack multiple items in the same Grid cell, so, you could have a full-size Grid and you could have an AbsoluteLayout as one of the things in the grid, but, everything else could be there, e.g. ScrollView, VerticalStacklayout, etc.